# How to fetch the roster using PostMan?

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to fetch the roaster using PostMan, using the [Microsoft Graph postman collection](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections)

1. Able to fetch userAccessToken
2. When I use "Teams->Members of a Team" Get Request - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{{TeamId}}/members, I get following **error**:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "422d9233-909a-43fd-bc2b-161f3dda9f7a",
            "date": "2020-03-05T09:09:55"
        }
    }
}
```

Without TeamId I will not be able to issue a GET request on /v3/conversations/{teamId}/members/

I have assigned following roles, as shown in image
[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you please paste your access token in [jwt.io](https://www.jwt.io) and see if it has all the required permissions to [get members of a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Hi, it seems that the app in azure ad doesn't have the permissions, please refer to the solution below I provided and have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the permissions to your app in azure add, the permissions are `User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Directory.Read.All` which mentioned in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the graph api.
[image]

Please refer to the steps below:

Go to your application in azure ad, you can search it with the "client_id", and click the button shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Search the permission and add them one by one.
[image]

After add all of the permissions, you need to click "Grant admin consent for *" button.
[image]

Then you can request for the token again and use this access token to request the graph api.

Hope it helps~

Comment: That worked, I am able to fetch the members of the team. Can you please confirm the API to fetch the roaster ?